# Two way binding with reactive forms without using ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have many many input need to be validated. So I use reactive form to validate them.
For example,

```
<input formControlName="testName">
```

In the constructor I defined the nested form.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   this.totalForm = this.fb.group({
       'subForm': this.fb.group({
           testName: [null, Validators.required]
       // ....
      })
   });
}
```

When I submit the data to the server, I want to use the fresh data from the input field. But I found the form control's data was not updated. The reason is that the form can't be two way binding unless using `ngModel`.

```
  this.dataTobeSubmited = this.totalForm.controls['subForm'].controls['testName'].value;
```

I use Angular 5, of course I can add `ngModel`. However if in the future we upgrade to the high version, it will becomes a problem since

> Using Reactive Froms with ngModel is deprecated in angular 6 and is
>   removed in angular 7

My case is a nested reactive forms, is there a better way to do two way binding?

**UPDATE For my binding**

The binding for the nested form group sample.

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
 <app-child [subForm]="profileForm.controls['subForm']"></app-child>
       <button (click)="whatIsTheFormValue()"> What Is My Value?</button>
 </form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dzabi

Am I right?

Comment: A more complete example might help us narrow down the issue. Also, for clarification, are you accessing the form group's value (this.totalForm.value), and it's value is not the most current one?

Comment: `this.totalForm.value.subForm.testName`, and NO, not add [(ngModel)] even in Angular 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for this.

1. A listener to any changes within the form. This [FormGroup.valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) may be what you need.

   Basically, the flow would be having a subscription to
   `this.totalForm.valueChanges`. Inside this subscription you can
   react on any changes from any input. Since this is an observable,
   you can also use operators such as `distinctUntilChanged` or
   `debounce`.
2. Have the submit button kick off a function, which grabs the form data via `this.totalForm.getRawValue()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tested getEawValue(). It was the original value.

Comment: Subscribe to valueChanges and examine the value. If it's still the original value then something is not right with how you are binding the form to the template.

Comment: valueChanges seems working with a simple form. To the nested form groups, I am not sure. Because this afternoon, I got something `max stack size overflow` error in valueChanges.

Comment: @Hello, `valueChanges` helps you examine your form values real time. You can try rx operators such as `debounce` to ignore changes from quick typing.

`getRawValue()` should give you the current form value. If not, like @JohnGallego said, you should double check the binding.

Comment: @NgocNamNguyen, I am not sure how to apply debounce.

Comment: Here is the doc https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html

Something like this `const formSub = this.totalForm.valueChanges.pipe(debounce(300)).subscribe(formData => { // your handler... })`

Answer (score -1):

u dont need ngModel. use `this.totalForm.value` to see the current  value of your form.

Comment: It is not. It is the original vale.

Comment: no. this.totalForm.value its a getter of FormGroup for current value. show the complete html of your component maybe y dont declare a [formGroup]="totalForm" in a wrapper for all of your inputs.

Comment: Trust me. I did many tests and I saw somewhere in SO said same thing. I don't recall where I can find it now.

Comment: I want to test it in a nested form group. For example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dzabi

Comment: if u need it in a child component inject the form. is the same object. see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eb8czt